# Pass/get drop down value into an sql variable without submit button/form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

I need to get the value of the selected item on the drop down selection populated from sql database. Then that value is needed in the sql statement to get the specific record.

I already populated the drop down selection. Code below

```
<select name="year" id="year">   
    <?php                             
       $query = mysql_query("SELECT distinct Year(fromdate) FROM emp WHERE empcode='$emp' order by Year(fromdate) desc");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $year = $row[0];
           echo "<option value=\"".$year."\">".$year."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

This is the php code for me to get the record using the value from the drop down.

```
<?php
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT salary FROM emp WHERE empcode='$emp' and Year(fromdate) = '$year'");
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
   $salary=$row[0];
?>
```

Then after that I need to pass the result to a textbox

```
<input id="salary" name="salary" value="<?php echo $salary; ?>">
```

What is the code needed for me to pass the selected item value from drop down "*year*" to PHP variable *$year* for sql statement? I already looked here in Stack Overflow for the answers but there is no question that look like mine.

What is wrong with people it needs sql why vote down

Comment: you need to make an xmlhttprequest to do that, make the request on change event of the select tag. and yes you can google that too

Comment: Warning... `mysql_*` functions are depreciated. Utilize `mysqli` or `PDO` for new code. Also, your SQL query will be wide open for sql injection attacks. Look into `prepared statements`.

Comment: @Ghost thank you for that i'll try to

Comment: @IncredibleHat again, i did not develop this. simply enhance. this was created way back 2000. this will be a major editing if i update it and this is currently being use so i do not have the time. thank you

Comment: "Again", when did you mention this was old code you are only editing, and not writing new?

Comment: my past question have the same comment so I am indicating AGAIN

Answer (score 2):

Do an ajax call to your php file, listening to your select onchange event, like so:

```
$('#year').on('change', function() {
            $.post( "path/file.php", { 
                year: $(this).val()
            })
          .done(function( data, status ) {

            console.log('data: '+data+' status: '+status);

            if(status == 'success'){
             //pass to your input ?
             //data is what your php file will echo/output
               $('#salary').val(data);
            }else{
              //how do you want to handle http error ?

            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @hexYeah the only problem is the variable still not able to get.

Comment: oops forgot to `()` here -> `year: $(this).val()`

Comment: Thank you very much @hexYeah , still have one minor issue :D There is a delay in the display in the salary textbox when selecting an item. I had to select 2 times before it appears on the textbox. Do you might know the cause on this?

Comment: Since its `onchange` you might want to have a blank `option` first

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get select box value without refreshing page then you need to do code with AJAX.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

On change please pass the year value to AJAX and then in AJAX file write down query for salary getting and after success full result put this value in salary filed using jQuery function